# onChange event for textarea instead of get value when needed

Tags: reactjs, textarea, redux, onchange, flux

I want to understand the performance implications of React's advocated way of handling textarea's value change.

Before React's one-direction data flow philosophy, one would do:

```
button.onClick( processInput(textarea.value) );
```

Now, one has to do

```
textarea.onChange( dispatch({ type: "inputChange", value: textarea.value }) );
button.onClick( dispatch({ type: "buttonClick" }) );

store(
    if (action.type === "inputChange") {
        this.lastInput = action.value
    } else if (action.type === "buttonClick") {
        processInput(this.lastInput)
    }
)
```

Is my understanding correct? Isn't this **much more** events compared to before? Why spam with many useless `inputChange` events? If my understanding is not right, what is the correct React way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

First, you're conflating a couple different things.  React's "controlled input" pattern doesn't require Redux.  You can implement controlled inputs inside a component, using local component state.  I have a gist discussing this concept at [react-controlled-inputs.md](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/d71cfc81687f11609d2559e8daee10cc).

Second, even if you're using Redux, you don't *have* to directly control the input with Redux state and actions.  Whether you do so is up to you.  In fact, there are times when you might want to buffer text `onChange` events locally in the component, and only dispatch a Redux action once the user is done typing.  I've got another gist demonstrating a buffering wrapper component at [FormContentsContainer.jsx](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/554cab15d83fd994dfab).

Finally, even if you do decide to directly control an input with Redux state, I'm not exactly sure why you're saying it's "more events".  The input's `onChange` is going to fire every time you type, regardless.  It's up to you whether you choose to do something with those events like translating them into Redux actions, or ignore them.  Or, if you prefer to use "uncontrolled inputs" and just ask the inputs for their values when someone clicks Submit, that's entirely up to you as well.

Comment: Right. I was also thinking the onChange event will be fired anyway. The other points are also valid

Answer (score 0):

*I think it would be better to extract actual code from [the Gist](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/d71cfc81687f11609d2559e8daee10cc) and put it here.*

If you need text value only on button click, you can ask it through `ref`

```
const MyComponent extends Component {  
  onClick() {  
    const input = this.refs.myInput;  
    const value = input.value;  
    // do something with the value  
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="text" ref="myInput" />
  }
}
```

You can get access to DOM element inside of your component using refs. If you need some simple solution, that will work for you.

Comment: I heard `ref` usage is generally discouraged, as it violates "one data flow direction"

Comment: While you are using `ref` only to read some properties, it doesn't break "one-way data-flow" rule, so you can safely use it.